# how to call function in setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, autocomplete

i'm implementing autocomplete, the goal is when a word is selected, i do not have to click the button, it'll automatically continue, following is my code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
                long id) {
              Logger.getLogger("test").info("selected");
              postData(this);
        }
    });
```

the log information is correct, and `postData(View view)`is the onclick function of the button, but there's error:`The method postData(View) in the type MainActivity is not applicable for the arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){})`. so how to call function inside the setOnItemClickListener?

Comment: use AvtivityName.this

Comment: post the code of postData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to,

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
            long id) {
          Logger.getLogger("test").info("selected");
          postData(arg1);
    }
});
```

Comment: this is in the MainActivity.java, so the parameter should be MainActivity.this?

Comment: but there's still error : The method postData(View) in the type MainActivity is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)

Comment: Try to call PostData(arg1)  .